# IntegrationModuleNotFound: Missing integration: fps

Tags: python, django

I am an amateur at Django and am following this github link to create an app for accepting payments.

I am successfully able to syncdb but when I run the server at 127.0.0.1:8000 I see the following error on the web page.

```
IntegrationModuleNotFound at /

Missing integration: fps

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.6.6
Exception Type:     IntegrationModuleNotFound
Exception Value:    

Missing integration: fps

Exception Location:     /home/arjun/merchant-master/example/billing/integration.py in get_integration, line 73
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/arjun/merchant-master/example',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Wed, 15 Apr 2015 21:00:05 -0500

TRACEBACK :

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                        resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve

                    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in url_patterns

                patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module

                    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

                __import__(name)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/arjun/merchant-master/example/urls.py in <module>

            url(r'^', include('app.urls')),

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py in include

                urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

                __import__(name)

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/arjun/merchant-master/example/app/urls.py in <module>

        amazon_fps_obj = get_integration("fps")

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/arjun/merchant-master/example/billing/integration.py in get_integration

                    raise IntegrationModuleNotFound("Missing integration: %s" % (integration))

        ...
    ▶ Local vars
```

My integration.py is under merchant-merchant/billing/integrations.py.
My INSTALLED_APPS are under merchant-merchant/example/settings/common.py.

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the project that you are using? https://github.com/agiliq/merchant

It has a requirements.txt file -- did you make sure to install what's in there?

Additionally, if you're just starting out with Django, I wouldn't use Django 1.6.6 -- the 1.6 version is now deprecated as both 1.7 and 1.8 have come out (with very important changes)

Comment: Hi, thank you for letting me know that. I got rid of that error without doing that but now i have issues with my templates. Trying to figure it out.